# Get List Of IE extensions inside IE extension

Tags: c++, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

I am trying to get list of all IE extensions present inside IE-8. along with installation date of extension, version and other information.

The way i want to do this is Create a new IE extension and fetch list of all other extension in there.

Is there any way in IE to do this? May be a high level API.

Any suggestions will be a great help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There a number of different types of 'extensions' in IE.
Toolbars, BrowserHelpers, accelerators, searchProviders, menu and context menu extensions. These in turn can be scripted, COM based or PE file types.

The registry paths for each type of extension is documented on MSDN.

Comment: Okay , what about installation date ?